# Ruby app times out (deployed on Amazon EC2 with Phusion Passenger)

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, passenger

I'm trying to deploy SequenceServer on Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu + Apache + Passenger), but it "hangs": http://ncwebguru.com/sequenceserver.

Same stuff happens to a "helloworld" app: http://ncwebguru.com/sequenceserver1

It works fine on my physical linux server (not EC2).

It doesn't log anything into apache log file so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. Any help on how to fix or troubleshoot the issue is greatly appreciated.

**Apache conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RackBaseURI /sequenceserver
    RackBaseURI /sequneceserver1

    <Directory /var/www/sequenceserver>
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/www directory:**

```
sequenceserver # sym link to /path/to/actual/sequenceserver/public
sequenceserver1 # sym link to /path/to/helloworld/public
```

**/path/to/helloworld directory:**

```
tmp/ # empty
public/ # empty
config.ru # helloworld ruby rack app
```

**config.ru**

```
app = proc do |env|
    return [200, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, "hello world"]
end
run app
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to set the `TimeOut` directive in Apache's configuration file.  Timeout is indicated in seconds. For example, the following will set timeout to 5 minutes:

```
TimeOut 300
```